# Matlab obtain Transformation matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, transformation

I have two Matrices: Matrix 1: **A**, that is the Matrix I have in the beginning and Matrix 2: **B** that has some values from **A** permuted. Both are filled with only ones and zeros (mainly zeros)

for example

```
    0 0 0          0 0 1
A = 0 1 0  and B = 0 0 0
    0 0 0          0 0 0
```

where I move the value 1 from the middle of matrix **A** to the top right corner in matrix **B**. I can do this manually by multiplicating with the Transformation-matrices **T1** and **T2**.

for the example above:

```
     0 1 0           0 0 0
T1 = 0 0 0  and T2 = 0 0 1  such that  P1 * A * P2 = B
     0 0 0           0 0 0
```

How can I calculate these two Transformation-matrices **P1** and **P2** with `Matlab` really fast (for matrices > 5000x5000) by only knowing matrix **A** and **B**?

---

The goal is to move some of the ones with every step on matrix **A**. As I have some other Matrices that act like layers, I would like to move them the same way, so I'd like to get **T1** and **T2** so I can change them the same way.

So the problem is that I have an island, that I get from GoogleMaps, that I convert in 0 (water) and 1 (land) and I randomly put People on that Map **M**. Then I randomly set the position of some people where **M** has a one. These people are set on matrix **A** with a one, rest is zero. The people move, the new position is given by Matrix **B**. While not all people are infected by zombies yet, I have a vector, that defines a subMatrix, where the zombies are. This little Matrix is the important one, so I move my zombie and some other attributes, that the zombie has (they are defined by other Matrices, I call them lazer Matrices). So I only want the changes of the Zombiematrix tracked (for that I need the Transformation Matrix), so that all layer matrices that have the attributes of the zombie Submatrix are moved the same way. The ZombieMatrix then grows bigger and bigger, the more people are infected. To save time, I look for a subMatrix that contains all the Zombies by each step and then perform the Transformationmatrix on this subMatrix.

I know that sounds all fuzzy, that's why I just asked the way above the line.

Comment: I don't think what you call a *permutation matrix* is actually a permutation matrix: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix

Comment: changed into Transformation

Comment: That doesn't quite solve the problem. You should rather state what these *Permutation/Transformation*-matrices should look like, as there will be many different solutions otherwise.

Comment: added the application to my problem

Comment: What do the matrices `A` and `B` look like more exactly? Where do they come from? For example you can't find permutation matrices (the way you want to use them) to get from `A = [1,1,0; 0,0,0; 0,0,0]` to `B = [1,0,0; 1,0,0; 0,0,0]`. What is the **real** application of this?

Comment: edit: I added the 'real problem', I'm sorry if it is described too fuzzy, it's about the idea

Comment: I think instead of matrix multiplication with a permutation matrix, you might want to consider indexing with permuted index numbers: `I=[1,8,7;2,5,4;3,6,9]; B = A(I);`. I think this should be a more feasible approach. Still it is not clear how the parts of your matrix will be permuted that stay zero. There are lots of possible ways to go from `A` to `B`. You will have to tell us which one you want. Otherwise this question will be closed as too broad.

Comment: You say *are moved the same way*, but if you have a small matrix `A=[1,0;0,1]` and goal `B=[0,1;1,0]`, which one is it: `A(1,1)` becomes `B(1,2)` or `B(2,1)`? If you can't tell us the answer to this, there is no way of answering your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your problem is nonlinear it can have multiple solutions, from which the comment of @knedlsepp. For this reason I think that resorting to a genetic algorithm might be a good option, naturally without looking at the performances...

Let us reformulate your problem as an optimization one

[image: 1, T2] = argmin norm(T1*A*T2-B), subject to: T1,T2 in [0 1]; T1,T2 in Integers]

Here we will adopt the Frobenius norm.

Then the code would look like

```
%// Build the test matrices
A = [0 0 0 ; 0 1 0 ; 0 0 0];
B = [0 0 1 ; 0 0 0 ; 0 0 0];
n = size(A, 1);

%// Define the optimization problem.
nvars = 2*n^2;
lb = zeros(nvars, 1);
ub = ones(nvars, 1);
intCon = 1:nvars;
options = gaoptimset();

%// Solve the problem.
[t,err,exitflag] = ga(@(t) fitnessfcn(t, A, B, n),  ...
                      nvars, [], [], [], [], lb, ub, [], intCon, options);

%// Retrieve the solution
T1 = reshape(t(1:n^2), n, n);
T2 = reshape(t(n^2+1:end), n, n);
```

and `fitnessfcn` is

```
function err = fitnessfcn(t, A, B, n)

T1 = reshape(t(1:n^2), n, n);
T2 = reshape(t(n^2+1:end), n, n);
E = T1*A*T2-B;
err = norm(E, 'fro');
```

I hope that by playing with the options you can apply this code to more realistic cases.

Comment: Interesting idea. I was only hoping the OP would clarify what he is really up to. In the end this could be a linear problem after all, e.g. if `A` and `B` themselves were permutation matrices or we had any other reason to know we could get from `A` to `B` by shuffling rows and columns...

Comment: Thank you! When I was writing this code I have observed a strange thing. In `ode45`, `fmincon` and many other functions we can pass additional parameters with `varargin`, but `ga` doesn't support it. I think that Mathworks should improve this.